# Loop through columns of excel pivot with vba

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to loop through the columns of a pivottable to add conditional formatting. I cant figure out how to select the data of a column. I only able to select the columnheader. In the following code I left the conditional formatting part away to reduce complexity.

```
Sub Format_Pivot_Columns()
  Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("piv_scrapedata")
  For Each ptFld In pt.ColumnFields
    ptFld.DataRange.Select
    Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
  Next ptFld
End Sub
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to duplicate your question but can't. I suggest you step through the code and set a Watch in Visual Basic on `pt` and inspect which fields it has (I didn't have `Columnfields`, but you may see it and see what fields `ColumnFields` has, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following code which works like a charm. Thanks for the inspiration!

```
Sub Format_Pivot_Columns()
 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("piv_scrapedata")
 For Each ptFld In pt.DataBodyRange.Columns
  ptFld.Select
  Selection.Interior.Color = vbYellow
 Next ptFld
End Sub
```