# hide pivot table columns based on condition

Tags: excel, vba

I have a pivottable like in the image. I'm trying to write a VBA code to automatically hide the entire column when there's no values in the column. so for example the column "Sum of 2013" should be hidden when applying the code

[image]

here's what I've tried

```
Sub HideEmptyPivotColumns()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim dataRange As Range

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

For Each pf In pt.PivotFields

    ' Get the data range for the column, excluding the header
    Set dataRange = pf.DataRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(pf.DataRange.Rows.Count - 1)

    ' Check if all cells in the data range are empty
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(dataRange) = 0 Then
        pf.Visible = False ' Hide the column if it's empty
    End If

Next pf
End Sub
```

but I got a run time error 1004 "unable to get the datarange property of the pivot field class"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30968662/478884 shows a different approach to looping over the columns